# Spring OAuth2 Resouce Server implementation for Google

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want to create Spring OAuth2 Resource Server for my client application which supports Google login.

Basically, my app users already made an authentication through the client app to the Google and they have google token.
My client app will send the token to my Resource Server.

As I read here https://arnoldgalovics.com/google-oauth-with-spring-security-as-separated-resource-server/, I have to create `GoogleTokenService.java` that implements `ResourceServerTokenServices.java`, which handles token validation.

Based on my research, I have few questions:

1. My resource server has to validate the tokens every time when it gets a request from the client app, Is this correct?
2. Doesn't the Spring has an implementation of `ResourceServerTokenServices.java` for Google? (and not only Google, I might need to support Github and Facebook logins too)

Quick image:
[image]

Comment: What version of Spring Security do you use?

Comment: Did you read https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/?

Comment: @dur, I am creating from scratch the project so I am using latest version. That documentation mentioned just one sentence about EnableqResourceServer, it mostly about doing single sign on but not token validation

Comment: There is a GitHub and Facebook example. Do you think that example is not validating the token? How should that work? You ask *Doesn't the Spring has an implementation of ResourceServerTokenServices.java* and you can find the answer in the link.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at OpenID Connect. See: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html (Example: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect)

Comment: Did you find your response?